# select() blocks instead of returning a timeout

Tags: c++, linux, select

As a background, I'm writing a multithreaded linux server application. Each child process has a connection associated with it and uses `select()` to see if there is data waiting to be read on the socket.

I've done some searching and for once I couldn't find any help to this problem.

First time actually posting to Stack Overflow, so I apologize if my formatting is crap.

```
//this first line switches my connection to non-blocking.
//select() still fails whether or not this line is in.
fcntl(ChildConnection -> newsockfd, F_SETFL, 0);    

struct timeval tv;
fd_set readfds; 

FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(ChildConnection -> newsockfd, &readfds);

tv.tv_sec = 3; //3 seconds of waiting maximum. Changing this does nothing.
tv.tv_usec = 0;

printf("-DEBUG: Child, About to select() the newsockfd, which is %i. readfds is %i.\n", ChildConnection -> newsockfd, readfds);

//if I feed this a bad descriptor (-1 or something) on purpose, it DOES return -1 though.
int result = select(ChildConnection -> newsockfd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

//this commented out line below doesn't even time out.
//int result = select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);

printf("-DEBUG: Child, Just  select()ed. result is %i. Hopefully that was >= 0.", result);

if (result < 0)
{
 DisplayError("ERROR using select() on read connection in MotherShip::HandleMessagesChild: ");
}
else if (result > 0) // > 0 means there is data waiting to be read
{
/* <--- Snipped Reading Stuff here ---> */      
}

//so if the code gets here without a result that means it timed out.
```

Unfortunately, the second print line (saying it has selected) is never printed. Does anyone know what's going on or have advice for me to try and debug this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fcntl(ChildConnection -> newsockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)`?

Comment: Don't forget to add \n to the end of you messages, or they won't be flushed. And: diagnostic output should go to stderr. And: most people like whitespace around `->`. I found it had to read, these `select(ChildConnection -> newsockfd + 1, ...);` lines.

Comment: @EddieEdwards - As far as I know, `0_NONBLOCK` is the same file descriptor as 0, so it doesn't make a difference. I remember trying both.

Comment: AIUI `fcntl(F_SETFL, x)` is effectively doing `flags |= x` so if x is 0 nothing happens.  O_NONBLOCK is 0x4000 in Linux 3.3 x86.

But this should not affect select.

Comment: @wilplasser - `DisplayError` calls `stderr` later after adding more diagnostic information, don't worry. :P
Also, it looks like I have whitespace around the `->` ?

Comment: @EddieEdwards - Thanks, good to know. Unfortunately `select()` is still being nasty. :S

Comment: The select() code looks correct to me.  Try putting a fflush(stdout); after your printf() call and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is `ChildConnection->newsockfd < FD_SETSIZE`?  Is your clock running? :-P  Also, try `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf()`.

Comment: Today, I suggest using `poll` in new code instead of `select` (which has known limitations and deficiencies). And `poll` is simpler to use than `select` IMHO. And you could `strace`  your code to understand where it is blocking. Don't forget to `fflush` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a blocking condition somewhere else.   Get your select() code working in a small test rig first and then transplant it.  Your comment in the code that "this commented out line below doesn't even time out" is verifiably incorrect:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
int main()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 3;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ time ./test

real    0m3.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Alternatively, try attaching a debugger to your hanging process and see where it is blocked.  Or watch it in strace(), etc...

Comment: I'll try this when I get back into the lab next week. Thanks for your help, and I guess I'll try the empty select again then. :P

Comment: My program definitely still hangs with the empty `select()`. I wonder what could be causing it to hang on the `select()` then, even if it's empty? I'll try doing some more in-depth debugging like you suggested.

Comment: Get this: The code hangs even without the `select()`. There are literally no lines of code between my two debug printouts, and the code doesn't even reach the second one. What the hell?

Comment: I replaced the second printf with a shorter variant and that printed out. Why would that be blocking it?